# Multi-file upload using Django not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Im having trouble on uploading multiple files. The uploaded files are pdf and only one is saved.

**views.py**

```
def attachments(request):
    to = TravelOrder.objects.order_by('-date_filling').last()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttachmentsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('attachment'):
                file_instance = Attachements(travel_order=to, attachment=f)
                file_instance.save()
                print('YEY')
                return redirect('attach')
    else:
        form = AttachmentsForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'employee/attachments.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class TravelOrder(models.Model):
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    wfp = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Wfp Where to be charged')
    purpose_of_travel = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_filling = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.purpose_of_travel

class Attachements(models.Model):
    at_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    travel_order = models.ForeignKey(TravelOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='attachment/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returing before the loop finishes.

```
for f in request.FILES.getlist('attachment'):
    file_instance = Attachements(travel_order=to, attachment=f)
    file_instance.save()
    print('YEY')
    return redirect('attach')
```

Take the return outside loop, so that the redirect happens only after saving all files. That means

```
for f in request.FILES.getlist('attachment'):
   file_instance = Attachements(travel_order=to, attachment=f)
   file_instance.save()
   print('YEY')
return redirect('attach')
```